# Positioning a scrollbar within a page rather than on the side

Tags: html, css, webkit, scrollbar

I'm trying to have the scrollbar be set within the page (as if it is floating within rather than stuck on the side). I've tried/ read just about everything. Using a margin/ padding -20px doesn't work and neither does left: '20px'. I keep ready and still am not finding any answers (worried i'm phrasing the question incorrectly.

I'm attaching the image of how it's supposed to look below.

[image]

Also, this is my code for the scrollbar so far:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-image: url("/assets/ScrollWheel.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 5px; 
  margin-right: -20px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
background: white; 
}
```

Any suggestions much appreciated, i've been pretty stuck on this one.

Comment: Watch this video: https://youtu.be/v_8CmC6cwUs

Comment: @muhammedoğuz the videos great but i've already customised everything. All I need now is to move it within the div and not on the border! Any thoughts?

Comment: Please share full code snippet.

Comment: Have u tried position: fixed